# Serialize only type=file in a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of controls in the form which includes several input type='file' boxes.  I want to validate all file inputs and ensure file is selected.  Due to some other problems I cannot use 'required' attribute.

I though of serialize the data of all file boxes and convert to an array and then validate the array.  If any of the file box doesn't have a value I can point the user to select a file. I am trying to put the code as below and it returns empty.

```
var dataString = $("#adminForm").find('input[type="file"]').serialize();
```

Can someone please advice how to serialize only the file boxes

**Update 1**

By seeing the answers I understand serialize is not the right way to validate forms.  I added a separate class 'filebox' for each file box and able to do the validation as below.

```
$('.filebox').each(function(i, obj) {
  if($('#'+obj.id).val() == 0) {
    /*raise error*/
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: What is ultimate goal? Sounds like you might want to use FormData API which will give you access to files themselves

Comment: @charlietfl - There are 10 file input boxes and what I want to validate all boxes and ensure they has value in it.  I thought of serialize it and convert to array and do the validation using jQuery.  If any of the box is empty then I can point to the user to select a file.

Comment: no real need to serialize them then, can just check that `val()` isn't empty

Comment: @charlietfl - Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried `val()` initially but I got stuck how to get values of all file boxes using single/minimal code.  I do not want to check each and every box.

Comment: will have to check each one regardless of approach. For minimal code can use `filter()`

Answer (score 0):

`.serialize()` will skip unnamed inputs. Add a `name` attribute to your inputs to include them, or remove to exclude.

Comment: I cannot remove the names of other controls because those are required in the action page.  The serialize I am trying to achieve here is to convert to an array and check if any of the file boxes are empty.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.serialize()` does not serialize file inputs: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/#entry-longdesc

You can use `FormData` object though.

```
$('#test').submit(function(e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var $copy = $(this).clone();
    // remove everything except file inputs
    $copy.find('select, input:not([type=file])').remove();
    var data = new FormData($copy.get(0));
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload.php', 
        data: data,
        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    }).always(function(xhr, data) { console.log(data) });
});
```

Watch the requests in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zka9k8Lf/

Comment: OP is only trying to validate file inputs